# PayPal Payments Advanced Transaction Types

Tags: paypal

This is probably a stupid question but I have to ask...

In the PayFlow Gateway Guide https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf
it says that with PayPal Payments **Advanced** the API does NOT support Sale or Authorization.  Surely that can't be right.  What is a PayPal Advanced account good for if you can't do a Sale or Authorization?

Additional information:

I'm testing using the Payflow_dotNET dll that comes with the PayFlow SDK.  Works fine in test mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean these lines: **NOTE: PayPal Payments Advanced and Payflow Link users cannot submit authorization transactions unless they obtain the Payflow SDK.** and **PayPal Payments Advanced and Payflow Link users cannot submit sale transactions unless they obtain the Payflow SDK.**

I agree that the verbiage is quite cryptic. But it is talking about non-hosted pages. If you are using Advanced you should not be using the API to submit credit card purchases. If you need to do this you would need to upgrade to Payments Pro.

With Advanced/Link you still have access to the other API calls that would be available with Payflow Pro, you just cannot process credit cards without using the hosted checkout.

Comment: I'm referring to the text at the bottom of page 26 of the Payflow Gateway guide.  Anyway this clears it up thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Page 14 and Page 65 of the Payflow link(PayPal Payments Advanced) developer guide:

Here are the accepted Transaction Types:

TYPE: A single letter that identifies the type of transaction (S: Sale or
A: Authorization). Transaction types are described on page 65.

Here is additional information on PayPal Payments Advanced/Payflow Link:

[PayPal Payments Advanced Getting Started](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/)

[Payflow Link Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowlink_guide.pdf)